# Initiating Flex DataGrid rendering

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, redraw, rerender, labelfunction

I have a DataGrid where some number of the columns can have a labelFunction.  The nature of the labelFunction result can change problematically(eg apply formatting, bypass formatting).

How do I get the DataGrid to re-render the visible items so that the labelFunction will be run again to get the new data.

I've tried the invalidateDisplayList, validateNow, and tried dispatching ResizeEvents on the DataGrid.  No success.

Comment: Have you tried yourDataProvider.refresh()  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Florian's comment is worth trying first but otherwise I believe invalideList will work:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#invalidateList()

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  I didn't want to refresh the data provider, since that will resort and re-filter the data, and that's overkill.